# How to share my public folder to other user in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I am a root user and created 3 users from root account. I have to share my documents and pictures to my all my 3 users, so that I placed my files to public folder available in my home directory. How can I share the public & its files to my all 3 users?

Note:
Other users should not have permission for delete or modify my files which shared.

Answer (score 0):

Create a group "groupeone":

```
sudo addgroup groupeone
```

add the users "username" to it:

```
sudo usermod -a -G groupeone username
```

from the folder you want to share, right click > permissions tab and under "group" select the correct permissions for the "groupeone" group.

hope this helps

Comment: I have done your steps in root account but the users does not seen the files. Where the shared files are located in users account?